# Подъём состояния при условном рендеринге в React.js

Tags: reactjs, usestate

У меня есть форма, в которой в зависимости от условия рендерится инпут для поиска или для добавления нового пользователя. Если я выношу инпут для добавления за пределы условия, то состояние изменяется, иначе - нет. Подскажите, как решить проблемы? В Функциональном компоненте.

```js
function App() {
   
   let [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

   let [formAction, setFormAction] = useState("search");
   let [inputForm, setInputForm] = useState(<SearchInput/>);

   const setNewUser = (newUser) => {
      setUsers([...users, newUser]);
      console.log(users);
   }

   const turnFormAction = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();

      if (formAction === 'search') {
         setFormAction("create");
         setInputForm(<CreateInput users={users} setNewUser={setNewUser}/>);
      }
      else {
         // formAction === 'create
         setFormAction("search");
         setInputForm(<SearchInput/>);
      }
   };

   return (
      <div className="app">
         <div className="control">

            <form className="control-form">
               {formAction === "search" 
               ? (
                  <button className="control-turn" onClick={turnFormAction}>
                     Add a user
                  </button>
               ) 
               : (
                  <button className="control-turn" onClick={turnFormAction}>Return to search</button>
               )}

               {inputForm}

            </form>

            <Output users={users}/>

         </div>
      </div>
   );
}

export default App;
```

Дочерний компонент:

```js
function CreateInput(props) {
   let createInput = useRef(null);

   const handleInputFocus = (event) => {
      createInput.current.setAttribute("placeholder", "");
   };

   const handleInputBlur = (event) => {
      createInput.current.setAttribute("placeholder", "Write a name of a user");
   };

   return (
      <fieldset className="control-create">
         <button className="control-create-button">Close</button>
         <input
            ref={createInput}
            type="text"
            placeholder="Write a name of a user"
            onFocus={handleInputFocus}
            onBlur={handleInputBlur}
         />
         <button
            type="button"
            className="control-create-button"
            onClick={() => {
               props.setNewUser(createInput.current.value)
            }}
         >
            Create
         </button>
      </fieldset>
   );
}

export default CreateInput;
```

Answer (score 0):

Сразу при смене состояния запускается перерисовка, и до следующей строки дело не доходит никогда. Код после установки состояния дальше не выполняется. Если хотите сразу две переменных состояния менять - это надо делать одной строкой, и обе переменный хранить в одном обьекте, примерно так.

```
  let [formAction, setFormAction] = 
  useState({status: "search", inputForm: <SearchInput/>});

  const turnFormAction = (event) => {
          event.preventDefault();
      if (formAction === 'search') {
         setFormAction({
             status: "create"
             inputForm:  <CreateInput users={users} setNewUser={setNewUser}/>
         });
         
      }
      else {
         // formAction === 'create
         setFormAction({
           status: "search"
           inputForm: <SearchInput/>
         });
      }
   };
```

Но если проще -
Вам надо по нажатию на кнопку просто менять состояния, без условного перехода и для простоты сделать его bool (false/true изначально)

```
let [formAction, setFormAction] = useState("true");    
   turnFormAction => () = {
      setFormAction(!formAction)
    }
```

А input отрисовывать в зависимости от состояния:

```
 <form className="control-form">
           {formAction 
           ? (
              <button className="control-turn" onClick={turnFormAction}>
                 Add a user
              </button>
           ) 
           : (
              <button className="control-turn" onClick={turnFormAction}>Return to search</button>
           )}

           {inputForm}

        </form>
```

Ну и еще нельзя менять свойства обьекта внутри своего обьекта - для этого есть состояние. Свойства это то что передается из родительского компонента. Это так же будет вести к ошибкам в дальнейшем

Comment: Всё ещё не понял. Проблема заключается в том, что функция setNewUser, переданная в CreateInput.js срабатывает неправильно - массив не обновляется (хотя если ввести значение и затем отрисовать заного компонент CreateInput.js, данные введённые в input добавляются в массив).

Comment: У вас идут подряд setFormAction setInputForm, обе функции изменяют состояние, то есть запускают перерисовку.  После того как сработала первая строка - начинается перерисовка и вторая строка не отрабатывает правильно

Comment: Посмотрите обновление ответа, пример для первого абзаца добавлен, как обновлять ожной строкой обе переменных состояния